# How can I make a div have a cut-out background style?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, as an example:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:  center;     
  display: flex;
}
.background {           
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #FBAB7E 0%, #F7CE68 100%);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.container {            
  background-color: white;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}
.button {
  background-color: red;    
  padding: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="background">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="button">
                    Button
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It produces the following result:

[image]

## What I want to achieve:

The `button` div to have the background color of the `background` div, but seam-less, like it is a hole into the `container` div.

I could add the `background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #FBAB7E 0%, #F7CE68 100%);` into the button styles, but it would look like this:

[image]

Which does not work as needed, since it is re-doing the gradient, not looking like it's part of the background below the container div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will probably reach the desired result:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:  center;     
  display: flex;
}
.background {           
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #FBAB7E 0%, #F7CE68 100%);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.container {            
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.button {
  background-color: transparent;    
  padding: 10vh;
  border: 50vw solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="background">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="button">
                    Button
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the changes:

```
.container {            
      background-color: transparent;
      overflow: hidden;
}
.button {
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 50vw solid white;
}
```

Both container and button are transparent, but button has a very large white border and container has overflow hidden.